Apache Camel with spring boot, retry behavior difference on exception
I am working on a migration project that involves camel routes and has the global and route level exception handlers running on a spring boot application. I noticed a difference in the exception handler retry behavior between the camel versions 4.3.0 and 4.9.0. Below is the code I used, and the corresponding logs that I got while running with the two different versions of camel.
Spring boot version is 3.4.0 and java version is 23.
I am trying to catch the ClassCastException that is not handled in the route level exception handler (doTry.. doCatch..). I expect it to be caught by the global exception handler (onException) which works fine in camel version 4.3.0 and the retries also happens perfectly before the routing ends.
But in camel version 4.9.0, the global onException handler never triggers and the application fails to catch the ClassCastException.
While reading the latest camel documentation, I found a line stating that the onException (global) handler will not trigger when the route level exception handler (doTry..doCatch..) is in place.
https://camel.apache.org/manual/try-catch-finally.html#_using_dotry_docatch_dofinally
With the next phase migration concerns in mind coming in the future I have the below questions. Appreciate any inputs/suggestions.
I'd like to know if this behavior was changed in some version between camel versions 4.3.0 and 4.9.0.
If I want to achieve the camel provided automatic retries for the below example in 4.9.0, how can I do it? I don't want to use any manual iteration mechanism for retries.
package com.apache.camel.test_exception;

import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ExceptionTest extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(true)          
            .log("Caught exception")
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliveryDelay(3000)
            .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
            .retriesExhaustedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
            .log("Exception Handled")
        .end();
        
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").scheme("http").port(8080);
        
        rest("/service/api/v1")
            .get("/testException")
            .routeId("rest-exception")
            .to("direct:exceptionRoute");
        
        from("direct:exceptionRoute")
            .routeId("exception-route")
            .log("Received request to test exception")
            .doTry()
                .throwException(new ClassCastException())       
            .doCatch(NullPointerException.class)
                .log("NullPointer Exception Caught")
            .endDoTry()
            .log("Route ended")
        .end();         
    } 
}

Logs for 4.3.0

2024-12-14T10:52:33.699+05:30  INFO 16524 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T10:52:33.704+05:30  WARN 16524 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: A1B32AE5C117F9F-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: A1B32AE5C117F9F-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T10:52:36.720+05:30  INFO 16524 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T10:52:36.720+05:30  WARN 16524 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: A1B32AE5C117F9F-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: A1B32AE5C117F9F-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T10:52:39.731+05:30  INFO 16524 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T10:52:39.731+05:30  WARN 16524 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: A1B32AE5C117F9F-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: A1B32AE5C117F9F-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 2 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T10:52:42.734+05:30  INFO 16524 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T10:52:42.735+05:30  WARN 16524 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: A1B32AE5C117F9F-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: A1B32AE5C117F9F-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 3 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T10:52:42.741+05:30  INFO 16524 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] rest-exception                           : Caught exception
2024-12-14T10:52:42.741+05:30  INFO 16524 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] rest-exception                           : Exception Handled
Logs for 4.9.0
2024-12-14T11:16:55.864+05:30  INFO 20908 --- [test-exception] [           main] c.a.c.t.TestExceptionApplication         : Started TestExceptionApplication in 3.152 seconds (process running for 3.61)
2024-12-14T11:19:32.081+05:30  INFO 20908 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
